# Entity field condition with "Not Contain" target_id for field multiple values

Tags: 8

Entity E have a field reference to Taxonomy T with multi value.

```
E.field_term.value = [
  ['target_id' => 1],
  ['target_id' => 4],
  ['target_id' => 7],
  ['target_id' => 9],
];
```

How to query the list of Entity E which not contain Term T (term_Id = 7).
I expect some thing like this:

```
$query = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')->getQuery();
$query->condition('field_term.entity:taxonomy_term.tid', '7', 'NOT CONTAIN');
```

But of course [QueryInterface::condition](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryInterface.php/function/QueryInterface%3A%3Acondition/8.2.x) do not accept **NOT CONTAIN** as operation.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you try <> or NOT IN?

Comment: I tried <>, and NOT IN. both not worked.

Comment: This is not possible with joined tables. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188969/how-to-use-entityquery-to-select-if-a-multiple-value-entityreference-field-does

Comment: Thanks @4k4 . seem like I should create a new field in the entity E to check for the condition.

Comment: The simplest method would be two queries subtracted with array_diff().

Comment: @4k4, Thanks. actually, I made it worked with 2 queries as you said before asking this question. but I hope that some where like %delta solution work also. but with your comfirmation, I know it's not available at the moment.