# EntityQuery, exclude nodes with NOT IN from a multivalued entity reference field

Tags: database, 9

Drupal v. 9.3.8
I recently used the entityQuery command and for simpler queries I had no problems.
Now I need to filter, as well as for the '=' and 'IN' operators, also the nodes, whose multivalued field has no values ​​or which does not have certain values. Reading the documentation I used the 'NOT IN' operator, but with poor results.
Example the query should return me the nodes that do not have the value 161 and 163
This is the query I simplified to try the 'NOT IN' operator

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->getQuery()
->condition('type'   , 'gestione' )
->notExists('field_attivita')
->condition( 'field_attivita', ['161', '163'], 'NOT IN' )
->execute();
```

I also tried with the '<>' operator but nothing to do

Among the various articles and questions I also read the post that comes close to my request
[How to use entityQuery to select if a multiple value entityReference field does not contain the id](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188969/how-to-use-entityquery-to-select-if-a-multiple-value-entityreference-field-does)
but I can't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: What's this notExists? What's with .target_id like shown in the linked answers?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think you can do this in a single query. I think you may need to 1. query for all, 2. query for the items with the ids you don't want, and then remove the ids from query 2 from the result set of query 1. Which, btw, is basically what the linked answer is saying.

Comment: I think the issue here is how the entity reference values are stored - each value in a multi-value field gets its own row in the db table. If your field had cardinality = 1, you could use not equals for each value you wanted to exclude.

Comment: sonfd, thanks for the reply and for the explanation. As mentioned, I recently approached queries (sorry also my elementary English, it will also be for this reason that I will be unclear) I did some tests based on your suggestions and maybe I understood what you said to me.
But there is one thing I don't understand. I have written some data for an example
Pos. Field_activity | $ var
1 300 | 161
2 161 | 163
3 400 |
4 163 |
5 empty |
6 200 |
7 163 |
8 empty |
...

Comment: if I use the condition
-> condition ('conflict_activity_field', [161, 163], 'IN')
it brings me back the nodes in position 2 - 4 and 7 of the example
-> condition ('conflict_activity_field', [161, 163], 'NOT IN')
should only destroy nodes that do not contain 161 and 163
Otherwise I didn't understand what the 'NOT IN' operator does the SQL manual confirms it
I am puzzled to do 2 queries and then the difference between the arrays, the query is complex and a lot of data may slow down the processing

Comment: leymannx, thanks for the reply but i didn't get it. notExist indicates whether the multivalued field has no data. target_id is the node's nid